# What's the phrase or word used to say that you bought a dog from a pet store and started raising it?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What's the phrase or word used to say that you bought a dog from a pet store and started raising it?
I am thinking that "adopt" would be the word, but I am wondering if there are phrases or words that are more commonly used to describe it.

> The family adopted a new dog from a store.
>
> The family adopted an old dog from a dog shelter.

Comment: *Foster* a pet?

Comment: "Foster" implies you will not be keeping the pet (people foster animals for rehabilitation or as part of their training as a service animal, for example). "Adopt" would absolutely be my word of choice here, no need to look any further!

Comment: @Emmabee That adds up. I agree. My version says "take care of a pet for a limited  time."

Comment: Yeah, adopting implies the intent and the commencement of raising, bringing up, nurturing. It's built-in.

Comment: _Adopt_ is fine for a 're-homed' dog from a shelter, but I think _buy_ or _get_ would be more usual in the case of a puppy acquired from a shop or a breeder.

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting that "adopt" is probably more common for shelter/rescue pets, but I definitely think you can still use it for pets obtained in other ways! "I got a new dog" also 100% fine (and probably more common I suppose), but I think "adopt" sounds nicer! :) It would still be the word I'd use personally. It definitely stresses that you care about the new animal. Dad who didn't want it would definitely just say, "we got the kids a puppy."